# Consulta por año en un DataGridView

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, windows-forms, datatables, date

Estoy haciendo un programa donde quiero consultar por año (en este caso serán 3 años, los cuales son: 2018,2019,2020) mediante `radiobutton`, al momento de seleccionar el `radiobutton` de 2018, quiero que aparezcan solo los que tienen año 2018, tengo una idea (obviamente no esta completa) de como indicarlo en el código el cual sería el siguiente:

```
SELECT nocontrato,inscripcion, nombre, apaterno, amaterno, telefono, direccion, registro, ntomas, correo, fallecimiento, divTerreno, herencia, documentos 
from usuarios 
where  inscripcion ='" + inscripcion + "'");
```

se que hace falta indicar que quiero seleccionar el año deseado, pero no se como, ¡¡AYUDA!!

Comment: Cual es el campo que te daria el año en tu consulta?

Comment: inscripción, ese me daría el año

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select nocontrato,inscripcion, nombre, apaterno, amaterno, telefono, direccion, registro, ntomas, correo, fallecimiento, divTerreno, herencia, documentos 
from usuarios 
where YEAR(campo_fecha) = 2018;
```

Por cada **RadioButton** vas a su **evento Click** y ejecutarías la consulta anterior cambiando por supuesto el año deseado, en este ejemplo te lo explico con **2018**. Como ves aquí en la **cláusula where** se usa la **función SQL YEAR** la cual recibe como parámetro un campo de tipo fecha y devuelve el año de dicha fecha.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte :D